# Java: stuck in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to create a program that takes 12 ints between 0 and 100, and puts them into an array.. then then two arrays multiply and the resulting 6 ints should go into a final array. But when I try to execute I'm able to enter the ints but nothing happens, I've a sneaky suspicion im stuck in a loop somewhere. Any advice would be appreciated.

**note**

I haven't included the calculations for the 2nd array as that's not where the problem is.. I can't even get to the 2nd array as its getting stuck somewhere

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calc {
    static int[] level = { 60, 40, 20, 30, 40, 70 };

    public static void workOut()
    {
        // after accepting an array of 12 ints should compute array of 6


        //  array declaration
        int[] nums = new int[12];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter int 1 then int 1a,");
        System.out.print("then int 2 then int 2a etc, until int 6 and 6a");


        if (!sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("Must be Int!");  
        }
        else
        {
            while (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {

                    if (sc.nextInt() >= 0 && sc.nextInt() <= 100)
                    {
                        nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
                    }              
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("Number between 0 and 100 please");
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You call scan.hasNextInt(), but how you declare scan? I think you must change it to sc.hasNextInt()

Comment: The best advice I can give is get an IDE (eg netbeans) and step through in debugger, then it'll be obvious where you get stuck

Comment: I'm using eclipse.. I'm pretty sure it has debugger, I'll check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
if (sc.nextInt() >= 0 && sc.nextInt() <= 100)
{
    nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

you're throwing away 2 input values for every 3 read. Doesn't look right, does it? You probably want to store the input and then compare:

```
int value = sc.nextInt();
if (value >= 0 && value <= 100)
{
    nums[i] = value;
}
```

You may also want to check for valid input as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    int value;
    do {
        value = sc.nextInt();
    } while (value < 0 || value > 100);
    nums[i] = value;
}
```

Comment: but if the input value is not valid, loop is also incremented.

Comment: @JamesLoper The best way to say thanks on this site is with a check mark. :)

Comment: @JamesLoper this code will not work. if you enter an invalid input then nums[i] will not assigned but loop variable i will be incremented. Did you run the code? or tested well?

Comment: Ok @ZongZhengLi you just put another useless loop which looks for integer.

Comment: @erencan Yes, thanks for the criticism; I'm a bit rusty at Java.

Comment: Congratulations @ZongZhengLi , you came to my answer finally.

Comment: @erencan. Yep, although I prefer the version where you don't need to duplicate the input line.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading integers in a completely wrong manner.

If you want to read 12 integer, for loop should be the first loop then you should control the input integer if it is valid.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
   int value = sc.nextInt();
   while(value < 0 || value > 100)
   {
       value = sc.nextInt();
   }
   nums[i] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
if (sc.nextInt() >= 0 && sc.nextInt() <= 100) {
    nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Assign `sc.nextInt()` to some value before. Because what you are doing now is unnecessary retrieving `nextInt()` and losing its value.

Change your code right in the beginning of your `while` loop like this:

```
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    int myInt = sc.nextInt();
    // ... rest of the code
```